# How to configure reserved namespace /__ of Firebase in Intellij?

Tags: firebase, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, firebase-hosting

[Firebase Hosting reserves URLs in your site beginning with `/__`.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls) Running `firebase init hosting` generates a file `index.html` that contains

```html
<!-- update the version number as needed -->
<script defer src="/__/firebase/6.3.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
<!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
<script defer src="/__/firebase/6.3.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/6.3.3/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/6.3.3/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/6.3.3/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<!-- initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded -->
<script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

These reserved URLs are available both when you deploy to Firebase (`firebase deploy`) or when you run your app on a local server (`firebase serve`). However, Intellij does not how to resolve these files and complains

```
Cannot resolve directory '__'
```

and

```
Unresolved variable or type firebase
```

in case of

```js
let app = firebase.app();
```

How do I configure Intellij so that it can resolve the URLs and the global variable `firebase`?

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: @RichArt I didn't solve it, but I'm still interested in a solution. If I find a solution, I will answer this question.